# How to search/replace a single inline with sed/awk?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a lot of files, where I would like to edit only those lines that start with `private`.

It principle I want to

```
gawk '/private/{gsub(/\//, "_"); gsub(/-/, "_"); print}' filename
```

but this only prints out the modified part of the file, and not everything.

**Question**

- Does gawk have a way similar to `sed -i` inplace?
- Or is there are much simpler way to do the above woth either `sed` or `gawk`?

Comment: Use `inplace` for awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the final print outside of the filtered pattern.  eg:

```
gawk '/private/{gsub(/\//, "_"); gsub(/-/, "_")} {print}'
```

usually, that is simplified to:

```
gawk '/private/{gsub(/\//, "_"); gsub(/-/, "_")}1'
```

You really, really, really, (emphasis on "really") do not want to use something like `sed -i` to edit the files "in-place".  (I put "in-place" in quotes, because gnu's sed does not edit the files in place, but creates new files with the same name.)  Doing so is a recipe for data corruption, and if you have a lot of files you don't want to take that risk.  Just write the files into a new directory tree.  It will make recovery much simpler.

eg:

```
d=backup/$(dirname "$filename")
mkdir -p "$d"
awk '...' "$filename" > "$d/$filename"
```

Consider if you used something like `-i` which puts backup files in the same directory structure.  If you're modifying files in bulk and the process is stopped half-way through, how do you recover?  If you are putting output into a separate tree, recovery is trivial.  Your original files are untouched and pristine, and there are no concerns if your filtering process is terminated prematurely or inadvertently run multiple times.  `sed -i` is a plague on humanity and should never be used.  Don't spread the plague.

Answer (score 1):

`GNU awk` from 4.1.0 has the in place ability.
And you should put the `print` outside the reg match block.
Try this:

```
gawk '/^private/{gsub(/[/-]/, "_");} 1' filename
```

or, make sure you backed up the file:

```
gawk -i inplace '/^private/{gsub(/[/-]/, "_");} 1' filename
```

You forgot the `^` to denote `start`, you need it to change lines started with `private`, otherwise all lines contain `private` will be modified.
And yeah, you can combine the two `gsub`s with a single one.

The `sed` command to do the same would be:

```
sed '/^private/{s/[/-]/_/g;}' filename
```

Add the `-i` option when you done testing it.